# angular - conditional element based on mat-select option

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How am I able to achieve the following:

```
<mat-select formControlName="ctrlName">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt.key">
        {{opt.label}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>

<div *ngIf=" SHOW IF A CERTAIN OPTION FROM THE LOOPED LIST ABOVE IS SELECTED "></div>
```

Sample list from the component:

```
options = [
    { key: 'keyOne', label: 'Key One 1' },
    { key: 'keyTwo', label: 'Key One 2' },
    { key: 'keyThree', label: 'Key One 3' }
]
```

Comment: Your code does not work. It should be `<mat-option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt.key">
        {{opt.label}}
    </mat-option>` and additionally `samplelist` should have the name `options`

Comment: @kboul , duely noted. Thanks! It was just a quick refactoring mistake (to make the short version)

Comment: Also change `{{option.label}}` to `{{opt.label}}`

Answer (score 2):

According to the **angular material** website ([example here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/aqgekqrrmjd?file=app%2Fselect-hint-error-example.html)), you need to add `[formControl]="selected"` to the `mat-select` component.

```
   <mat-select [formControl]="selected">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt">
            {{option.label}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>

    <div *ngIf="selected===<your_specific_value>"></div>
```

Comment: @snkv I have updated the code and the link as well. Please try now.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the usage of formControls , I had to reference the entire form and specify the value:

```
*ngIf="form.value.specValue == 'valueName'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this solution

I have create a demo on **[Stackitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-umnvkh?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.html)**

> Component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <div formGroupName="ctrlName">
        <mat-select formControlName="key">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt.key">
                {{opt.label}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>


        <div *ngIf="myForm.get('ctrlName').value.key=='keyOne'">First Selection</div>

        <div *ngIf="myForm.get('ctrlName').value.key=='keyTwo'">First Selection</div>


    </div>
</form>


<div *ngIf="selectedData && selectedData.key=='keyOne'">First Selection</div>
```

> Component.ts

```
myForm: FormGroup;
  options = [
    { key: 'keyOne', label: 'Key One 1' },
    { key: 'keyTwo', label: 'Key One 2' },
    { key: 'keyThree', label: 'Key One 3' }
  ]

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      ctrlName: this.fb.group({
        key: ['keyTwo', Validators.required],
        label: ['Key One 2'],
      })
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but as stated above, using [(ngModel)] and formControlName is not a valid option. How can we bypass this?

Comment: This is the exact error: **Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with 
    reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed 
    in Angular v7.**

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

Add `[(ngModel)]="selectedCtrlName"`

add if condition base on value/key

`*ngIf="selectedCtrlName === opt_key"`

**TS**

```
selectedCtrlName: any;
```

Final Result

```
<mat-select formControlName="ctrlName" [(ngModel)]="selectedCtrlName>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt.key">
        {{opt.label}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>

<div *ngIf="selectedCtrlName === 'opt_key'"></div>
```

In your case should be something like

```
<div *ngIf="selectedCtrlName === 'keyTwo'"></div>
```

Please note that `opt_key` is the value of the option which can be a number, string etc.

Comment: Thanks, however, using **[(ngModel)]** and **formControlName** is not a valid option. How can we bypass this? >

Comment: This is the exact error: **Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with 
    reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed 
    in Angular v7.**

Comment: @snkv Did you try setting `[(value)]="selected"` to the `mat-select` component?

Comment: @AnkitSharma , yes, and I am giving you the exact console output ^

Comment: Reactive forms don't work with banana box binding. This is by design.